# Deleting or assigning zero to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, delete-operator

In what situations in the codes, should we `delete` a given `pointer` and where had we better `assign zero` to it, instead of `deleting`?

Comment: `delete p` deletes the object `p` is pointing to (and strictly speaking not the pointer). If you assign zero to a pointer, the object the pointer was pointing to is unaffected!

Comment: ...thus: you delete when you have to delete, and you may assign a zero, if the value of the pointer is no longer a valid address

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use either `Foo f;` or `auto f = std::make_unique<Foo>();`? (in neither of those cases would you have to worry about doing a `delete`)

Comment: @tobi303: Apparently all are changing. By `delete` we change both the the value of the pointer (the address) and the object's value (usually to a big negative number). @Michael: I haven't been taught the topics you mentioned. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: I dont understand at all what you mean with "usually a big negative number". Once the object is deleted, it does not have a value anymore. Once you delete it, trying to access its value is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

> In what situations in the codes, should we delete a given pointer and
>   where had we better assign zero to it, instead of deleting?

You delete a pointer if you created it using `new`. And actually you are deleting an object to which the pointer points, not the pointer itself. Although syntax lets you write `delete ptr` indeed. But what gets deleted is where `ptr` points. Not `ptr`.

Assigning `nullptr` to the pointer, if you didn't do `delete` before, doesn't help - you actually lose an address of object where that pointer was pointing and creating a memory leak (of course if there were no other pointers pointing to the original object). e.g. this is bad:

```
double* pvalue  =  new double;   
..
pvalue = nullptr; // Bad - pointer to original memory is lost now
delete pvalue; // What should I delete?
```

So if you used `new` for creating an object you need to `delete` it before assigning a `nullptr` to the pointer.

So after `deleting` it is ok to assign `nullptr` to the pointer.

---

All that said you need to consider if you really need dynamic memory allocation (e.g. `new`) in your code.

Comment: It's only a memory leak if this was the last pointer to the object.

Comment: In modern code 'nullptr' should be used instead of 'NULL'.

Comment: Politely, I advise against just editing your post to recommend "NULL (or `nullptr`)" with the latter being relegated to parentheses. Just recommend `nullptr`. `NULL` is a relic from C, just means 0 (with all the limitations that entails), and has no place in modern style. Edit: Ah, done :)

Comment: Thank you all and a special thanks to Giorgi for the answer and also clearing up the notion of memory leaking for me. And about `nullptr`, its work seems to be like assigning zero, in effect!

Comment: @Giorgi: In your last sentences, I think, the part "assigning a `nullptr` to it" should be changed to "assigning a `nullptr` to the `pointer`" :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think that one should delete a pointer when the object it refers to is not needed anymore, after it has been created by using `new`. And one can assign zero (preferably `NULL`) to a pointer after it has been deleted to show it is not pointing to something anymore. One can then test afterwards whether or not a pointer equals `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

> In what situations in the codes, should we delete a given pointer and
>   where had we better assign zero to it, instead of deleting?

You never just assign zero to a pointer instead of deleting it. The rule is that if you use new to allocate memory then you should always use delete to deallocate it.

Sometimes you might need to null a pointer *after* you delete it depending on your requirements.

Example where nulling does not matter:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
        : data_(new int(1024))
    {}

    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete data_;
        // we don't need to null data_ here because we can be sure that it is not used after MyClass is destructed.
    }
private:
    int* data_;
};
```

Example where you should null a pointer after deletion:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
        : data_(nullptr)
    {}

    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete data_;
    }

    void CreateData()
    {
        if(data_ == nullptr)
        {
            data_ = new int(10);
        }
    }

    void DeleteData()
    {
        delete data_;
        // we must make sure to null data_ here otherwise we will have issues calling CreateData again.
        data_ = nullptr;
    }

private:
    int* data_;
};
```

**Note**
The above examples should only be used to demonstrate the above points as they do not adhere to [the rule of 3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).